# How to get many list from apex class in js controller in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am new to the lightning component. I want to get two lists in the js controller how it's possible?

```
 public class ContactListController {

    
@AuraEnabled
public  static List<Contact> getContactlist(){
        List<integer> listTwo=new list<integer>();
         listTwo.add(1);
        listTwo.add(4);
         listTwo.add(9);
        List<Contact> listOne= new  List<Contact>([select id, FirstName,LastName,email,Phone from Contact]);
    
    
       return listOne;
        
    }

}
```

Js controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action= component.get('c.getContactlist');
       
        action.setCallback(this,               
             function(response){
            var responseValue = response.getReturnValue();
            
           component.set('v.contactlist',responseValue);
        },'SUCCESS');
        $A.enqueueAction(action,false)
        
    }
})
```

Now Question is how can we get two lists in js controller. the   `getContactlist` return only  one list. I want to return many things from the same method like integer , string, boolean etc

Answer (score 2):

This example is not especially realistic, but the general solution remains the same: define a custom type that wraps all of the data you're interested in transferring, and return an instance of that class:

```
public class MyDTO {
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Integer> ints { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

See the [Aura Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_returning_data.htm) for more information and details on shipping data back and forth between Aura and Apex.

Comment: so how can I get these two lists in the js controller?

Comment: David has linked the resources to get you started, if you are expecting someone to provide you a complete code sample, note that this is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: Your `getReturnValue()` result has a shape as a JavaScript object that matches your Apex class shape.

Comment: like that `` component.set('v.contactlist',responseValue.contactlsit);`` and  `` component.set('v.intlist',responseValue.ints);`` ?

Comment: @fawad, if you are new to lwc and/or aura, I would strongly suggest you follow the corresponding trailhead modules.

Comment: I studied the trailhead